# Proporción de un valor específico en un DataFrame con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Si quisiera sacar la proporción de cuántas veces se repite un valor único en una columna de un DataFrame de Pandas, ¿Cuál sería la sintaxis?
 `df['columna'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: pues las veces que se repite un valor único es 1, sino no sería único :/

Comment: Creo que no me estoy explicando bien, en el siguiente enlace se hace lo que quiero hacer pero en general con el dataframe, no con un valor en específico. (ejemplo 5). https://re-thought.com/pandas-value_counts/

Comment: En otras palabras, si en una columna tengo los valores 1, 2 ,3 y 4 repetidos varias veces, quiero saber el porcentaje de qué tanto se repite 4 en esa columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías calcular para todos los números y tomar el valor que deseas del `dict` de salida:

```py
num=5 # Proporción de veces que se repite el numero #num
resultadoGeneral=df['columna'].value_counts(normalize=True)
resultadoEspecifico=resultadoGeneral[num]
print(resultadoEspecifico)
```

resultado

```
0.4 # representando 40%
```

También puedes hacerlo con `list.count(num)` de la siguiente forma:

```py
listaNumeros=df['columna'].values.tolist()
porcentaje=listaNumeros.count(num)/len(listaNumeros)
print(porcentaje)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba.